# Rails update_attributes always redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm writing a edit page for a record in my database, I want to redirect if the update was successful and render the edit page again for any errors. Here is the code:

```
def edit
    @list = List.find(params[:id])

    if @list.update_attributes(params[:list])
        redirect_to(root_path)
    else
        render('edit')
    end
end
```

The redirect fires as soon as I launch the edit page, before any changes are made or the submit button is clicked.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit action should look like this:

```
def edit
  @list = List.find(params[:id])
end
```

It renders the edit view. The form should point (and probably is) to the update action that should look like so:

```
def update
  @list = List.find(params[:id])

  if @list.update_attributes(params[:list])
      redirect_to(root_path)
  else
      render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: That seems it would work, but how can I send the ID along to the update method?

Comment: You won't have to if you use the `form_for(@List)` when declaring your form in the view.

Comment: I am using form_for @list, :url => {:controller => 'lists', :action => 'update'} Error: Couldn't find List without an ID

Comment: just use `form_for @list` Rails will figure out the right path : )

Comment: Nope, that creates a whole world of errors :P List is not a resource, so how would it figure the path out?

Comment: So use `form_for @list, :url => {:controller => 'lists', :action => 'update', :id => @list.id}` XD